# Laravel - Cloud9 Paginator generating unwanted https links

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, laravel, pagination

I just moved my Laravel project over to cloud9 and after spending a bit of time figuring out how to properly configure MySQL to work on it (locating the correct hostname) I have run into another rather odd problem I didn't have in the vagrant box: the site's entire pagination changes the URL from HTTP to HTTPS when you click any of the page links.  This in turn causes an SSL connection error.  Does anyone know how to fix this or how to simply change the URLs via .htaccess?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to create a solution finally with .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```